# When are RKHS closed under absolute value?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, reproducing-kernel-hilbert-spaces

Let $\mathcal{H}\subset \mathbb{R}^X$ a real reproducing kernel Hilbert space (RKHS) with reproducing kernel $k : X\times X\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$.

Is then $\mathcal{H}$ closed under absolute value, that is do we have that

$$\tag{1} f\in \mathcal{H} \quad\text{implies}\quad |f|\in\mathcal{H}\ ?$$

(Here, $|f| : X \rightarrow\mathbb{R}, \  x\mapsto |f(x)|$, is simply $f$ composed with the absolute value $|\cdot|$ on $\mathbb{R}$.)

If $(1)$ does not hold generically, are there conditions on $k$ for which it is true?

Comment: In general it is not true, e.g. take $X=\mathcal H$, when you get just linear functions. But I don't know the answer to your 2nd question.

Comment: I think the Sobolev space $H^{s}(\mathbb R)$ is a RKHS for every $s>1/2$, if I understand the definition. The property $(1)$ that you wrote should hold true for $s\leq 1$ and fail for $s>1$ (I did not check carefully this last part, the threshold value could be larger than $1$, I don't see it at the moment). In principle, one could try to compute the reproducing kernel for given $s$ and see what happens to it when $s$ approaches $1$ from above and from below. I wouldn't expect to find anything meaningful, but if I had to start from scratch this would be an interesting explicit example.